# Epson v850 scanner driver compatibility with modern operating systems?

Tags: windows, negative-scanner, os-x, epson

From Epson's page for the [v850 Scanner](https://epson.com/For-Work/Scanners/Photo-and-Graphics/Epson-Perfection-V850-Pro-Photo-Scanner/p/B11B224201), it states under the "General" section that the list of supported operating systems are:

> - Windows® 8 – 8.1
> - Windows 7
> - Windows Vista®
> - Windows XP®
> - Windows XP Professionnal x64 Edition
> - Mac OS® X 10.6.x – 10.10.x

None of the listed operating systems are current.  The last release for OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) was in July 2017 and Windows 8.1 was in released in 2013.

So do the Epson drivers work under the current versions of each operating system (Windows 10 and/or macOS 11, Big Sur)?

And if not, are there any work arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the [support page](https://epson.com/Support/Scanners/Perfection-Series/Epson-Perfection-V850-Pro/s/SPT_B11B224201) from the page you linked you will see that both Windows 10 and macOS 11 are available from the support pulldown... If you also look on the Windows drivers page you will see that the Epson Perfection V850 Pro driver is compatible with

> Windows 10 32-bit, Windows 10 64-bit, Windows 8.1 32-bit, Windows 8.1 64-bit, Windows 8 32-bit, Windows 8 64-bit, Windows 7 32-bit, Windows 7 64-bit, Windows Vista 32-bit, Windows Vista 64-bit

And the Mac drivers page shows compatibility with

> macOS 11.x, macOS 10.15.x

Comment: Well now I feel foolish for simply believing the main page.

Comment: No worries... You'd expect a company like Epson to keep their product page updated, but apparently not.

Comment: Maybe I can rationalize it by the fact they're about to release a new version, and so didn't allocate the resources?  (That is just a pure wish on my part, but I do note that the introduced the v750 in 2006 and then the v850 in 2014.  So it's almost time for a new version)